# Unity loading Mapbox scene asynchronously before tiles are ready

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mapbox

I have a Unity scene which uses Mapbox to show the user's location. I have created a loading prefab which displays for the transition to this screen, so the scene should remain hidden until fully loaded. The Map Visualizer should prompt the loading screen to stay active until the scene is ready, but the scene loads before the Mapbox tiles are visible?

```
using System.Collections;
using Mapbox.Unity.Map;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LoadScene : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject LoadingScreen;
    public Slider slider;
    public Text ProgressText;
    public AbstractMapVisualizer MapVisualizer { get; set; }

    public void SceneLoader (string name)
{
    
StartCoroutine(LoadAsynchronously(name));
}

IEnumerator LoadAsynchronously (string name)
{
    AsyncOperation operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(name, LoadSceneMode.Single);

    LoadingScreen.SetActive(true);

    while (!operation.isDone)
    {
        float progress = Mathf.Clamp01(operation.progress / .9f);
        slider.value = progress;
        ProgressText.text = Mathf.Round(progress * 100f) + "%";

        yield return null;
    }
    MapVisualizer.OnMapVisualizerStateChanged += (s) =>
    {
        if (s == ModuleState.Finished)
        {
            LoadingScreen.SetActive(false);
        }
    };
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox tiles start loading when the scene gets loaded, so you just need some delay before hiding your loading screen, after the scene gets loaded.
In your case that would be after your while loop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Adding delay is not a good practice as you never know how long to wait for.  Use Task and await the async process to finish.